# Getting/Interpreting the Trend and Seasonality from TS Using R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, model

I'm working on extracting the trend/seasonal relatives of my TS data. I'm working with monthly data beginning Jan 2016 and ends on Apr 2020. I have 47 columns I'm calculating the seasonal index for, but will only include a single column as an example. I've written a script to calculate the seasonal index which is similar to how the `decompose` function calculates these values. I now want to use the `tslm` function in the `forecast` package to run a regression. My model will have a trend variable and 11 dummies for each month. I'm using the below SO question as a reference. An example of the data and my model is included below.

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1640904, 1646339,    1672164,    1682396,    1717000,    1750968,    1775434,    1782130,    1782803,    1707311,    1679556,    1718607,    1632339,    1615307,    1629484,    1654750,    1663248,    1700227,    1696307,    1688116,    1688840,    1639536,    1618165,    1624451,    1570132,    1542625,    1551257,    1562385,    1592886,    1645617,    1665081,    1655570,    1682867,    1681761,    1651978,    1656306,    1608402,    1611011,    1612756,    1635810,    1674892,    1691025,    1713028,    1713154,    1702144,    1716481,    1681540,    1674598,    1631436,    1621157,    1646172,    1662194))

SeasonalIndex<-function(x){
  trnd=ma(x,order=12,TRUE)
  detrend=x/trnd
  m=t(matrix(data=detrend,nrow=12))
  seasonal=colMeans(m,na.rm=T)
}
SI=sapply(df, SeasonalIndex)
SI<-as.data.frame(t(SI))
colnames(SI)<-c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

myts<-ts(df, frequency = 12, start=c(2016,1),end = c(2020,4))
dat<-data.frame(a=myts, time=as.numeric(time(myts)))
model<-tslm(a~trend+season,dat)
```

I'm trying to obtain the trend and seasonal factors. Is a regression with a trend variable and 11 seasonal dummy variables the appropriate approach? I'm also thinking that I should actually log transform my data.

[Getting Trend and Seasonal Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716954/getting-trend-and-seasonal-models-from-stl-decompose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with lots of time series, it is much easier to use tsibble objects than ts objects. Here is an example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

set.seed(999)

# Create data frame with 47 columns
df <- matrix(exp(rnorm(47 * 64)), ncol = 47)
colnames(df) <- c(letters, LETTERS)[1:47]
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

This is just a random matrix of the same shape that you describe. Now we turn it into a tsibble object.

```r
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    Month = yearmonth(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "1 month", length = NROW(df)))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Month, names_to = "Series", values_to = "value") %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Month, key = Series)
df
#> # A tsibble: 3,008 x 3 [1M]
#> # Key:       Series [47]
#>       Month Series value
#>       <mth> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 2016 Jan a      0.754
#>  2 2016 Feb a      0.269
#>  3 2016 Mar a      2.21 
#>  4 2016 Apr a      1.31 
#>  5 2016 May a      0.758
#>  6 2016 Jun a      0.568
#>  7 2016 Jul a      0.153
#>  8 2016 Aug a      0.282
#>  9 2016 Sep a      0.380
#> 10 2016 Oct a      0.326
#> # … with 2,998 more rows
```

You were using classical time series decomposition. A more reliable approach is an STL decomposition. This is additive, but we can compute multiplicative seasonal indices by applying it to the logged data.

```
# Seasonal indices via STL decompositions
stl_indices <- df %>%
  model(
    STL(log(value) ~ season(window = "periodic"))
  ) %>%
  components() %>%
  # Turn into indices
  mutate(
    stl_index = exp(season_year)
  ) %>%
  select(Series, Month, stl_index) %>%
  # Pull out one year of indices
  group_by(Series) %>%
  filter(year(Month) == min(year(Month))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Give months names
  mutate(Month = month(Month, label = TRUE))
stl_indices
#> # A tsibble: 564 x 3 [1]
#> # Key:       Series [47]
#>    Series Month stl_index
#>    <chr>  <ord>     <dbl>
#>  1 a      Jan       0.989
#>  2 a      Feb       1.42 
#>  3 a      Mar       1.62 
#>  4 a      Apr       0.687
#>  5 a      May       1.11 
#>  6 a      Jun       1.17 
#>  7 a      Jul       1.23 
#>  8 a      Aug       0.586
#>  9 a      Sep       0.938
#> 10 a      Oct       1.07 
#> # … with 554 more rows
```

Something similar can be done using regression. The fable package uses `TSLM` as the equivalent to the `tslm()` function from the forecast package.

```r
# Seasonal indices via regression with trend and seasonal dummies
reg_indices <- df %>%
  # Fit models
  model(
    TSLM(log(value) ~ trend() + season())
  ) %>%
  # Extract seasonal coefficients
  tidy(fit) %>%
  filter(str_detect(term, "season")) %>%
  # Add Month column
  mutate(Month = parse_number(term)) %>%
  # Add January 0 coefficient
  bind_rows(tibble(Series = unique(df$Series), Month = 1, estimate = 0)) %>%
  # Normalize around 0
  group_by(Series) %>%
  mutate(estimate = estimate - mean(estimate)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Turn into indices
  mutate(reg_index = exp(estimate)) %>%
  # Give months names
  mutate(Month = month(Month, label = TRUE)) %>%
  select(Series, Month, reg_index) %>%
  arrange(Series, Month)
```

We can combine both indices into one data frame to see that they are relatively close to each other in this case. The STL ones are generally going to be more reliable because they allow for nonlinear trends while the regression approach assumes a linear trend.

```
# Combine both indices
stl_indices %>% left_join(reg_indices)
#> Joining, by = c("Series", "Month")
#> # A tsibble: 564 x 4 [1]
#> # Key:       Series [47]
#>    Series Month stl_index reg_index
#>    <chr>  <ord>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 a      Jan       0.989     0.978
#>  2 a      Feb       1.42      1.43 
#>  3 a      Mar       1.62      1.66 
#>  4 a      Apr       0.687     0.712
#>  5 a      May       1.11      1.10 
#>  6 a      Jun       1.17      1.15 
#>  7 a      Jul       1.23      1.20 
#>  8 a      Aug       0.586     0.578
#>  9 a      Sep       0.938     0.929
#> 10 a      Oct       1.07      1.07 
#> # … with 554 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for the package suggestions and truly helpful information!